# VBA: Different worksheets, same named cell ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using code that returns "range of object_global failed" with the second part of the below code (Worksheet 3 code) highlighted.

Would using the same named ranges, but on different worksheets, as I have done below be causing this?

```
Worksheets(2).Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Worksheets(3).Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Given that a named range is specific to a sheet and range, yes.

Comment: A named range can be specific to the page, which means only formulas on that page will be able to call it, or workbook specific mean it can be called from anywhere in the workbook.  To see which  go to formulas====>Name Manager and look at the properties of the named range.

Comment: Most likely yes. You could check the names' scopes and change to workbook or just get the string addresses of those two ranges and put those addresses in your `Range` definitions.

Comment: You should be able to avoid these kind of conflicts by specifying the workbook and worksheets in all references. 'Thisworkbook.sheets(2).range("LTSDI")'

Comment: @ScottCraner `Defined Names` can be used in formulas anywhere in a workbook regardless of their scope, only condition is to include the entire path of the `Defined Name` in the formula, so let’s say we have a `Defined Name` called `Test1` in worksheet `Sht 1` of workbook `Book10` the syntax to use that `Defined Name` in a formula in another workbook is: `'[WorkbookName]WorksheetName'!DefinedName` i.e. `'[Book10]Sht 1'!Test1`

Answer (score 5):

To be more clear than what the comments above suggest, named ranges work in the following ways.

Named ranges can have 2 scopes:

- **Workbook Level**
- **Sheet Level**

Excel allows identical named ranges within the same workbook for **as long as it has a different scope**. In other words, Excel does not allow identical range names at the Workbook Level or Sheet Name.

As an illustration, the following is okay:

- **myRange** = Sheet1!$A$1 Scope: Workbook
- **myRange** = Sheet2!$A$1 Scope: Sheet2

But the following is not:

- **myRange** = Sheet1!$A$1 Scope: Workbook
- **myRange** = Sheet2!$A$1 Scope: Workbook

All that said, the way to refer to named ranges follows:

**Workbook Scope Level**

> From any cell on any sheet: `=MyRange`

**Worksheet Scope Level**

> From any cell within the worksheet, and as long as there are no other
>   identical named ranges scoped at the workbook level: `=MyRange`
>
> From any cell within any worksheet, or if there is an identical named
>   range scoped at the workbook level: `='Sheet1!myRange'`

Lastly, if you do have two identical range names, one scoped at the workbook level and one at the sheet level, if you do not qualify the sheet, the workbook scoped range will be used as default.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is throwing the,

> Run-time error '1004':
>      AutoFill method of Range class failed

This is due to the lack of a defined parent worksheet in the latter half of each command.

```
With Worksheets(2)
    .Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

With Worksheets(3)
    .Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

The above defines the parent worksheet with a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Each [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) is prefixed with a period (aka *full stop* or `.`) which explicitly references the parent worksheet noted by the With ... End With.

If you opted for the simpler [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) you could avoid the With ... End With as the range only has to be referred to once.

```
Worksheets(2).Range("LTSDI:LTEDI").FillDown
Worksheets(3).Range("LTSDI:LTEDI").FillDown
```

Finally, the following illustrates what is necessary for your code to work if you choose to repair the original instead of one of the above.

```
Worksheets(2).Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Worksheets(3).Range("LTSDI").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets(3).Range("LTSDI:LTEDI"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```